# Swift - CABasicAnimation not working with CALayer

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cabasicanimation, caanimation

Here is my code about add a layer with animation added.

```
let myLayer: CALayer = .init()
let myAnimation: CABasicAnimation = .init(keyPath: "bounds.size.height")

// for myLayer to center of superview
let centerPoint: CGPoint = .init(x: mySuperview.bounds.width / 2, y: mySuperview.bounds.height / 2)

myLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
myLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
myLayer.position = centerPoint
myLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

myAnimation.fromValue = 20
myAnimation.toValue = 100
myAnimation.duration = 1
myAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.0
myAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

myLayer.add(myAnimation, forKey: "bounds.size.height")

mySuperview.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
```

and `myLayer` was appeared at correct position. but added animation isn't working.

not only about `bounds.size.height`. `frame.size.height`, `transform`, `opacity`... I tried all of them but It isn't changing.

I am confused because I have a recollection of working well easily by above code.

Did I skip anything?

Comment: That's because you are setting a wrong key path.

Comment: @ElTomato - `bounds.size.height` is animatable, just fine. I used the above code and it worked fine (other than needing to add a `.cgColor` to `myLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor`).  Byoth, you'll have to share more information (for example, where/how you're calling this), because when I use the above, it works fine. There's something going on not included here. Personally, I'd rather animate with UIKit instead of CoreAnimation, but this should work.

Comment: Perhaps use the view debugger to make sure `mySuperview` is where you think it is (e.g. confirm that it's in the view hierarchy, what its frame is, etc.)...

Comment: @Rob ah! That's removed to during move into stackoverflow.. `.cgColor` is added in my real code. (post edited)

Comment: @Byoth I copied your code, and it's just working fine!

Comment: @Rob hmm I confirmed with your advice. Everything looks normal except an animation... superview's frame, view hierarchy, all of them are what I wanted.
I calling this after view did load.(superview always loaded when calling)

Comment: @AymanIbrahim Could you tell me your Xcode version? why only me lol

Comment: I do not think that matter, try posting all the code you are using.
it's Version 9.0.

Comment: Byoth, like Ayman and I said, the above animates fine. (There are minor things I'd change, but the only major problem with the above is that it returns back to the initial frame when the animation is done.) If you're seeing no animation at all, then edit your question, outlining the precise steps to reproduce the problem, because the above is insufficient. The problem must rest elsewhere. Try creating a blank project and do whatever needed to reproduced the problem. If worst comes to worst, upload that blank project somewhere for us to look at.